# XCode 8 change Size to different

Tags: interface-builder, xcode8

Using the newest Xcode, when editing a XIB there are no devices listed below the "Size" drop down. I used this heavily to see how things would lay out on various devices. I know when using a storyboard, there should be selections in the main storyboard to choose a device to "view as". I do not use storyboards, however. How do I choose a device to "view as" in a single XIB file.

Comment: I'm looking at a XIB file right now and there is a "View as:" panel below the main visual editor area. (Xcode 8.2.1) - Is this not there for you?

Comment: @RyanH. Ah I see it now. I was looking for the full menu, but it's collapse as just text which seems not clickable. It is, however, clickable and expands to the full menu selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xcode 8 - Size Classes**

To access the size class options for a XIB file (or a Storyboard), click on the "View as:" bar as shown here:

[image]

It will then expand to reveal the different device sizes and orientations:

[image]